# Unable to do C# Restful authentication (API Key/Secrete is correct)

Tags: c#, rest, web, http-post, restful-authentication

I would like to convert the authenticated REST request of JS (below) to C# code - using RestSharp lib (as shown) I seems not building the signature correctly. Please help..

Rest response keep response with **"Invalid API Key"** (which the key/secret are confirmed correct)

```
// sample code using the crypto lib to build the RESTFUL request
const crypto = require('crypto')
const request = require('request')

const apiKey = 'test'
const apiSecret = 'test'
const url = 'version/auth/abc'
const nonce = Date.now().toString()
const body = {}
const rBody = JSON.stringify(body)

// try build the RESTFUL signature here using crypto lib and use sha384

// Not quite sure what's the update does here though.
let signature = `/api/${url}${nonce}${rBody}`
signature = crypto
  .createHmac('sha384', apiSecret)
  **.update(signature)**
  .digest('hex')

// all code above is fine. And this is the sample code only, and trying to do something same in C# and have tried the following. I believe is the way create the "signature" issue.
```

I have written the C# code below, but not working, please kindly point out, I guess is the signature building is incorrect somehow.

```
    private uint64 _nonce = UnixTimestamp.CurrentTimeInMillis;
    public uint64 MyNonce()
    {
       return ++_nonce;
    }

    private string MySignature(string jsonData)
    {
        byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonData);
        _hasher = _hasher ?? new HMACSHA384(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(PrivateApiSecret));
        byte[] hash = _hasher.ComputeHash(data);            
                return GetHexString(hash);
    }


    // try to build the request below in a method.
    // only show method body below:
    // using the RestSharp client to build Restful req.
    var client = new RestClient(new Uri("the API address goes here"));
    var request = new RestRequest(string.Format("auth/abc"), Method.POST);

    // try do something similar and serialize to json in order to build the signature.
    Dictionary emptyBody= new Dictionary();
    string url = "version/auth/abc";
    string rawBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(emptyBody);
    string sign = $"/api/{url}{MyNonce()}{rawBody}";

    string sign64= Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sign));                
    string signature = MySignature(sign64);

    // add the key and signature above to the header of reqest.
    request.AddHeader("nonce", GetNonce());
    request.AddHeader("apikey", PrivateApiKey);
    request.AddHeader("signature", signature);

    // well, you don't need me to explain this line don't you?
    var response = request.Execute(....);
```

Hope this is clear enough. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know what is different between the two calls http calls.

Comment: It uses https for sure: e.g. https://api.abc.com. I don't know, I try to convert it into C# and do something similar, but responses not expected.